# How to secure home environment when testing vulnerable VMs

Tags: ctf, vmware

I'd like to practice CTFs and cyber attacks on vulnerable VMs downloaded from seemingly reputable sources.

Which are the basic guidelines for securing the environment and avoid that malware (if any) would infect the host (my laptop)? Is setting up a Custom Specific Virtual Network (for just the attacking VM and the vulnerable VM, without any connection to outside or the host) enough?

Using VMWare Workstation Player 16.

Comment: Making sure all your software is up to date (VM, host OS) would be the most important thing.

Comment: Verify that the VM can not reach any service of your network, or run the vm with no network connectivity if possible